# How do I store data in class that is globally accessible file

Tags: android

I am trying to make a basic app that allows a user to create an account and sign in. How do I save this information in a file that is globally accessible to all classes?

I tried using SharedPreferences, and was able to store the information but could not figure out how to retrieve it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                String usernameData = username.toString();
                String passwordData = password.toString();
                String emailData = email.toString();

                //How do I store data in java?

                if (username != null && password != null && email != null){
                    savePreferences("usernameKey", usernameData);
                    savePreferences("passwordKey", passwordData);
                    savePreferences("emailKey", emailData);
                    Intent nextpage =new Intent(accountcreation.this,    information.class);
                    startActivity(nextpage);

                }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `SharedPrefetences`? It makes it very clear how to retrieve values. Also, show us your `savePreferences(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).commit();
```

Take from: [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)